# Route with nullable parameter problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a page where you edit "usergroups". And I have this in my controller:

```
public ActionResult UsergroupEdit(int? usergroupID)
```

both edit and create on the same view.

and in global.asa:

```
 routes.MapRoute("AdminUsergroupEdit", "Admin/Usergroup/Edit/{usergroupID}",
            new
            {
                controller = "UsergroupsAdmin",
                action = "UsergroupEdit"
            }
                );

 routes.MapRoute("AdminUsergroupCreate", "Admin/Usergroup/Edit/",
            new
            {
                controller = "UsergroupsAdmin",
                action = "UsergroupEdit"
            }
                );
```

And when using this it works:

```
Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UsergroupEdit", new { usergroupID = Model.Usergroup.UsergroupID })
```

But this one doesnt match, whats the problem with this one?

```
Html.ActionLink("Create", "UsergroupEdit")
```

How can I make it match in both cases? since "UsergroupID" is nullable, but in both cases should match that action?

/M

Comment: I tried your code and I see nothing wrong. Did you add other routes than the ones you have shown here?

Comment: The links exists in "Userdetails"-view, /Usergroup/12, so it automatically adds /12 to the second link too. So both links go to same address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Html.RouteLink` instead of `Html.ActionLink`:

```
Html.RouteLink("Create", "AdminUsergroupCreate", "Create",
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "UsergroupEdit" } } )
```

[`RouteLink` is faster and never picks the wrong route.](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/03/18/38085/)